# Unexpected web view in Windows Search

Tags: windows-10

Recently I had some kind of IE-based web view in Windows Search result - the one you activate with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. It happened two times so far.

It looks like this:
[image: Win+S with some stange web view]

Comparing some details, this looks like top of some Bing search. I'm not sure if it is intended functionality or not - tiles seem a bit off, but maybe that's because of notebook's small screen. Killing the "Search" process - the one with white magnifying glass icon on blue tile - in Task Manager and letting it restart generally fixes it: i.e. this online search tiles are no longer displayed in UI.

Is that some kind of built-in functionality? If it is so, how to completely disable it?
If it is not, is there any standard hooks (special files, directories) in search where malicious agent could inject this stuff. Built-in Windows Defender doesn't report anything either in background or on full scan.

Just in case, no it is not how "All" tab usually looks to me. As I already mentioned, for months of using this shortcut - I've seen this strange web view only two times. Search results look completely random, not related to terms entered and those result do not react in any way if I type something new in search.

That's how search usually looks to me:
[image: Win+S, usual]

Comment: Your screen looks correct.  Click on Documents (top row) to restrict your search to your local computer. I do not think you can set Documents to be default.

Comment: No. After I kill process and pretty much 99.99% of time I ever use search there's zero any "web" tiles. Additionally those results are completely random, are not related to search terms and do not change when I type something new.

Comment: I do not kill Search processes because then tends to break Search and its setup.  So if you are trying to use it in a non-standard way (a) I do not do this and (b) there may be unintended results.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: Just in case, simply searching google images for "windows search" shows dozens of screenshots with "All" tab showing none of this random web junk. So no, I don't think it is "correct".

Comment: "is that some kind of built-in functionality?" - Yes;  Bing search results were added to Windows 10 3 years ago.  In most recent versions a separate process is responsible for those results which I believe is `SearchUI.exe`  So what exactly is your question?  Your screenshots appear to be working and are exactly what should be displayed.  It appears you are either running 1909 or 2004 based on the look of that UI.

Comment: @Ramhound Those are NOT SEARCH RESULTS, just a random junk from Bing that does not correspond to terms entered AT ALL. Do you see "test" anywhere in those results? Next time it happens I can type whatever you want and screenshot it do demonstrate that it is random junk. Nor does it appear when I usually press Win+S, only in rare 1% cases, so it can't be normal. Second screenshot is normal. First is not.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - The search results are also not in English.  All I can say is those are Bing results presented by SearchUI.  While I would have completely different results, those are exactly, the screenshot appears to be exactly what I would expect.

Comment: @Ramhound How do you explain then that I get no such "web results" 99% time when I use Win+S - i.e. 2nd screenshot. I had a chance to reboot today and running search was first thing I've done to ensure it can't be explained with any dirty state - no web, as expected. I also pinged several friends and asked to screenshot their UI on "All" tab while typing something obviously online-related like "wikipedia": no web either,